# Python - Lock values in iteration process

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, iterator, block

I state that am not a pytho expert. Through this post I would like to understand how I can iterate a process using locked values in the mentioned process (ex: for loop).

I'm gonna to explain what I'm looking for step by step.
at the beginning I build a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

# Build the Dataframe

data = {'Col_1' : pd.Series(list(range(10,53,3))),
   'Col_2' : pd.Series(list(range(30,45))),
   'Col_3' : pd.Series([0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0])}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['Result'] = 0
data['Result_1'] = 0

# Define a constant

c = 2
```

Below there is the result of the above code.

```
    Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Result  Result_1
0      10     30      0       0         0
1      13     31      0       0         0
2      16     32      1       0         0
3      19     33      0       0         0
4      22     34      0       0         0
5      25     35     -1       0         0
6      28     36      0       0         0
7      31     37      0       0         0
8      34     38      1       0         0
9      37     39      0       0         0
10     40     40      0       0         0
11     43     41      0       0         0
12     46     42     -1       0         0
13     49     43      0       0         0
14     52     44      0       0         0
```

Having said that, I want to create an iterative process (ex: for loop) which pursues the follow conditions:

1. if Col_3 = 1 lock the value in Col_1, use this last to execute operations in Col_2 until the value in Col_3 become equal to -1, and put the result into the 'Result' column.
2. if Col_3 = -1 use the locked values of the previous point, do the same operation "of the previous point" and in addition mutiply the obtained result for the defined constant 'c'. Put the result into 'Result_1' column.
3. Otherwise put 0 values into both columns ('Result' and 'Result_1').

Below is shown how the iteration process has to work.

```
    Col_1  Col_2  Col_3   Result   Result_1
0      10     30      0        0          0
1      13     31      0        0          0
2      16     32      1  (16-32)          0
3      19     33      0  (16-33)          0
4      22     34      0  (16-34)          0
5      25     35     -1        0  (16-35)*c
6      28     36      0        0          0
7      31     37      0        0          0
8      34     38      1  (34-38)          0
9      37     39      0  (34-39)          0
10     40     40      0  (34-40)          0
11     43     41      0  (34-41)          0
12     46     42     -1        0  (34-42)*c
13     49     43      0        0          0
14     52     44      0        0          0
```

Below is shown the expected Dataframe.

```
    Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Result  Result_1
0      10     30      0       0         0
1      13     31      0       0         0
2      16     32      1     -16         0
3      19     33      0     -17         0
4      22     34      0     -18         0
5      25     35     -1       0       -38
6      28     36      0       0         0
7      31     37      0       0         0
8      34     38      1      -4         0
9      37     39      0      -5         0
10     40     40      0      -6         0
11     43     41      0      -7         0
12     46     42     -1       0       -16
13     49     43      0       0         0
14     52     44      0       0         0
```

In conclusion I know that I can get the same result, in a simpler way, without using the iterator but in this specific case I'm looking for someone available to explain me how I can do the process explained so far through the use of iterator (the iterator can be for loop, while or something else).

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to iterate over the index of `data` with a `for`-loop:

```
on = False  # Switch starts with off (= False)
for i in data.index:
    if on:
        if data.at[i, 'Col_3'] == -1:  # Check if -1 in Col_3 is reached
            on = False  # Switch off (= False)
            data.at[i, 'Result_1'] = c * (col_1 - data.at[i, 'Col_2'])
        else:
            data.at[i, 'Result'] = col_1 - data.at[i, 'Col_2']
    else:
        if data.at[i, 'Col_3'] == 1:  # Check if 1 in Col_3 is reached
            on = True  # Switch on (= True)
            col_1 = data.at[i, 'Col_1']  # Store value of Col_1 in this position
            data.at[i, 'Result'] = col_1 - data.at[i, 'Col_2']
```

The variable `on` tracks if in which "phase" the program is (in-between 1 and -1 in Col_3 or not).

A version with `while` that iterates over the index:

```
iterator = iter(data.index)
while True:
    try:
        i = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    if data.at[i, 'Col_3'] == 1:  # Check for 1 in Col_3
        col_1 = data.at[i, 'Col_1']  # Store value of Col_1 in this position
        while data.at[i, 'Col_3'] != -1:
            data.at[i, 'Result'] = col_1 - data.at[i, 'Col_2']
            try:
                i = next(iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                break
        # Value -1 in Col_3 reached
        data.at[i, 'Result_1'] = c * (col_1 - data.at[i, 'Col_2'])
```

Without the `for` the iteration needs to be done explicitly with `next()`. This is done inside a `try`-`except` block to catch the `StopIteration` exception and then `break` out of the loop. If you want to see what happens without catching it try:

```
iterator = iter(data.index)
while True:
    next(iterator)
```

In both version I left out step 3 because the zeros are already there.

In general: `for` loops are a more "controlled" environment. `while` loops often offer more flexibility, but need the explicit iterating.

(There are other ways of iterating over a DataFrame, like `data.iterrows()` or `data.itertuples()`.)

Comment: Genius, This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks Timus, I really appreciate the time that you spent answering me.